# Como passar variável entre views?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Meu problema é o seguinte. O dashboard do meu projeto possui um input onde o usuário insere o número do processo e clica em pesquisar, conforme código abaixo:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="<?= base_url() ?>processo/pesquisar" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" style="width: 250px;" name="pesquisar" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o número do processo" required>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md"> CONSULTAR</button>
        </div>            
    </form>
```

Ao clicar em pesquisar, eu chamo o método pesquisar do controlador Processo, conforme abaixo, que chama o método get_processos_like do model, Processo_model:

```
public function pesquisar() {
    $this->load->model('Processo_model', 'processo');
    $dados['processo'] = $this->processo->get_processos_like();
    if (!$this->processo->get_processos_like()) {
        $data["msg"] = "Processo não encontrado.";
        $this->load->view('includes/msg_erro', $data);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('/listar/listar_processo_adv', $dados);
    }         
}

 #Método get_processos_like do Model:

 function get_processos_like() {
    $termo = $this->input->post('pesquisar');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('nprocesso', $termo);
    return $this->db->get('processo')->result();
}
```

Esse método retorna os dados do processo pesquisado para view listar_processos_adv.php, que exibe todas as informações do processo e possui um link chamando outra view, conforme abaixo:

```
    <div class="row">     
                <div align="center">
                    <button type="button" title="Detalhes" onclick="window.location.href = '<?= base_url('processo/custas')?>'" class="btn btn-primary>INFORMAÇÕES DE CUSTAS</button>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Até aí tudo funcionando, ocorre que preciso passar o número desse processo encontrado e exibido para outra view, chamada de listar_processo_custas.php, que exibe além de algumas informações sobre o processo, exibi as suas custas (despesas) do processo. Pois bem meus caros, dei muita volta, mas a pergunta é simples: Como faço para passar uma variável para uma outra view no Codeigniter?

agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passar o valor via GET na URL para o método `custas`. Sugiro utilizar `<a>` no lugar de `<button>`. Você pode utilizar `class="btn btn-primary"` no `<a>` também. Ficaria basicamente assim:

```
<div class="row">     
    <div align="center">
        <a href="<?=base_url('processo/custas/'.$codProcesso)?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">INFORMAÇÕES DE CUSTA</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lembrando que no Codeigniter as variáveis que são passadas via GET podem ser pegadas a partir dos parâmetros do método do controlador. No seu caso. o método `custas` do controlador `processo` deve ser assim: `public function custas($codProcesso) {...}` e dentro deste método você vai buscar no banco os detalhes do processo  e mandar pra página de detalhes que você desenvolver. ($this->load->view(...))

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Simples assim, muito obrigado meu caro @Paulo Weverton

Comment: Teria como passar o codProcesso de forma oculta? Pois ele está apacendo na url.